# If $ f*g$ is a polynomial of degree at most $m$ for all $g \in C_{0}^{\infty} $. Show $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $m$ almost everywhere

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

$C_{0}^{\infty}$ denotes the set of smooth functions with compact support.
In attempt of this, I've evaluated the convolution at the (m+1)th derivative to obtain
$$ \frac{d}{d^{m+1}}(f*g) =\int f(x-y)g^{(m+1)}(y)dy = 0 $$
But am lost in how to show that this implies f is a polynomial of degree at most m.

Comment: Hello reinin, and welcome to MathStackExchange. I have a few doubts on your notation: What do you mean with $C_0^{\infty}$? Also, shouldn't your derivative be $\frac{d}{d^{m+1}}$ instead of $\frac{d}{d^k}$?

Comment: ah yes sorry I'll change the derivative so it is correct. and by $C_{0}^{\infty}$ I mean the set of smooth functions with compact support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general $f$ is a distribution. If you assume $f$ is a $L^1_{loc}$ function it doesn't change the argument

- If its distributional derivative $f^{(m+1)} $ is not the $0$ distribution then $f \ast g^{(m+1)}=f^{(m+1)} \ast g  \ne 0$ for some $g \in C^\infty_c$.
- If $f^{(m)}$ is not constant then $f^{(m+1)}$ is not the zero distribution.
- So the $m$-th derivative of $f-c_m x^m$ vanishes and by induction $f$ is a degree $\le m$ polynomial.

If you don't like distributions and their derivatives, pick some $\phi \in C^\infty_c, \int \phi = 1$ and replace $f$ by the smooth functions $f_n = f \ast n\phi(n.)$. You'll find that each $f_n$ is a degree $\le m$ polynomial which implies since $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$ converges (to $f$) in the sense of distribution that the same holds for the limit.

Comment: I am new to distributions and have a question concerning them. The general definition for a distribution f acting on a test function $\phi$ is $f[\phi] := \int f(x)\phi(x)$ and the derivative of $f$ as a distribution is given by $f'[\phi] \equiv -f[\phi'] $. But in my question, we are considering convolution, so in this case, does the derivative of $f$ as a distribution become the usual convolution derivative $f'(x)*\phi(x) = f(x)*\phi'(x)$?

Comment: Equivalently distributions are the (continuous) linear maps $g \in C_c^\infty \mapsto f \ast g \in C^\infty$ such that $(f \ast g)(x+a) = (f \ast g(.+a))(x)$. The (continuous+$C^\infty$) follows from being well-defined, and it is what implies $(f \ast g)^{(m)} = f \ast g^{(m)}$. Then $f^{(m)}$ is just defined as $f^{(m)} \ast g =f \ast g^{(m)}$, the point is to show everything is compatible with the usual objects when $f$ is a (continuous, smooth, integrable) function

Comment: Because the $f_n$ in my post $\to f$ the distributions extend the functions in the same way that $L^1$ extends $C^0$ and $\Bbb{R}$ extends $\Bbb{Q}$

Comment: Ah ok thank you. So there are different possibilities of $f$ as a distribution? e.g. $f[\phi] = \int f(x)\phi(x)$ is one possibility for $f$ as a distrubution and the convolution $f*\phi = \int f(x)\phi(x-y)$ is another possibility for $f$ as a distribution, each giving rise to their own distributional derivative?

Comment: No I'm saying $f[\phi(-.)] = f \circ \phi(0)$ so the two (pairing, convolution) are the same. The advantage of the convolution point of view is that continuity of $f$ is made clear : $f \ast \phi \in C^\infty$ for $\phi \in C^\infty_c$